# cuda gpu freeing memory allocated through cudaMemcpyToSymbol

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu

Do we have to free memory allocated through  cudaMemcpyToSymbol? If so, how do we do so? The programming guide says cudaGetSymbolSize is used to get size of allocated memory, so memory is allocated for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cudaMemcpyToSymbol` does not allocate memory, it simply copies to a statically declared global or constant memory symbol in the current context. And `cudaGetSymbolSize` returns the size of any statically declared symbols. There is no dynamic memory allocation involved in either operation.